# What all is stored when we say synchronization context is stored?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

When await is encountered, the control passes to the caller while awaited call waits for response.

Before control is passed to caller, the synchronization context is stored.

In case of windows app the synchronization context is the main UI thread. Thus when the await is complete, the saved context is restored and the rest of the code below the await executes with the original synchronization context.

I want to ask- what all items are stored in the synchronization context. For example:

1. Current thread
2. Local variable values
3. What else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is nothing interesting (unlike ASP.Net apps which store request and culture), there some tracing IDs preserved possible... Would be interesting to see your reasoning for your examples to store -"current thread" (as it is always the same main UI thread) or "local variables" (as there really none as when asycronous part starts the original method returns/finishes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing stored in the `SynchronizationContext`. The `SynchronizationContext` is itself captured and stored by the [asynchronous state machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.iasyncstatemachine), and used at the right moment by invoking its [`Post`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post) method. The local state is stored in the asynchronous state machine, along with the captured context.

Comment: What about local and global variables?

Comment: @variable it's not the `SynchronizationContext`'s business to deal with local and global state. This class only knows about delegates. It takes a delegate and knows when and where to invoke it.

Comment: By delegate do you mean the code after the await?

Comment: @variable essentially yes.

Comment: Who stored local and global state info so that when it resumes it knows what the state was.

Comment: @variable that's the job of the async state machine. But I have not dived in the depths of the async state machines, so I don't know exactly what is stored there. If you are interested you could search for "c# async state machine" in your favorite search engine, and you'll find lots of stuff to read!